# How to detect a full black color image in OpenCV Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I want to write code in python to print a text when the input image is perfectly black and no other colors are present in it. Which are the functions to be used?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
# open the file with opencv
image = cv2.imread("image.jpg", 0)
if cv2.countNonZero(image) == 0:
    print "Image is black"
else:
    print "Colored image"
```

You basically check if all pixel values are 0 (black).

Answer (score 6):

```
image = cv2.imread("image.jpg", 0)
if cv2.countNonZero(image) == 0:
    print "Image is black"
else:
    print "Colored image"
```

The snippet above provided by @ebeneditos it's a good ideia but in my tests opencv returns an assertion error when capturing a colored image.

According [opencv community](https://answers.opencv.org/question/172784/count-non-zero-error/), *countNonZero()* can handle **only single channel images**. Thus, one simple solution would be to convert the image to grayscale before counting the pixels. Here it is:

```
gray_version = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
if cv2.countNonZero(gray_version) == 0:
    print("Error")
else:
    print("Image is fine")
```